# How modal box show by mouse click in select box at the Laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I wish to show modal box when mouse clicked to "Andre..." at the list select box in the Laravel code as below. but this is not working. Could you tell me where is incorrect to work?

**Select Box**

[image]

**Variable define in Controller**

```
$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type')
                    ->unique(function ($item){
                        return $item;
                      });;
```

**HTML(Laravel Blade)**

```
Job Type Field
<div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="job_type">
    {!! Form::label('job_type', 'Type:') !!}

    {!! Form::select('job_type', $job_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type']) !!}
</div>
```

**Modal view**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="jobListModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Set in new job type.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>New Job type:</p>
          <input type="text" id="textInput">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
    if ('Another' == this.value) {
        $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
    }
});
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    var newType = $('input#textInput').val();
    $('select#job_type option:last')
        .after('<option value="' + newType + '" selected="selected" >' + newType + '</option>');
    $('#jobListModal').modal('hide');
});
```

**Inspection**

[image]

Comment: Corrected code snippet of you change event handler,
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
    if ('59' == this.value) {
        $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
    }
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This : if you want to match by dropdown text

```
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
    if ('Another' == $('#job_type option:selected').text() {
        $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this code part to:

```
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
    if ('59' == $(this).val()) {
        $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: Change the "Andre" to the id value "59" since $(this).val() will actually refer to the value attribute and not text attribute.

Comment: it also not working :( There is no JS code error in inspection.

Comment: Try alerting something inside the if condition to see if it gets there.

Example: alert("foo");

Comment: There is nothing to be seen with alert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165825/discussion-between-galanx-and-magnetic).

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried This

```
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
    if (59 == $(this).val()) {
        $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
    }
});
```